# Altering the Hive table partitions by reducing the number of partitions

Tags: hive

**Create Statement:**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tab1(usr string)  
                PARTITIONED BY (year string, month string, day string, hour string, min string) 
                ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
                LOCATION '/tmp/hive1';
```

**Data:**

```
select * from tab1;

jhon,2017,2,20,10,11 
jhon,2017,2,20,10,12 
jhon,2017,2,20,10,13
```

Now I need to alter `tab1` table to have only 3 partitions `(year string, month string, day string)` without manually copying/modifying files. I have thousands of files, so I should alter only table defination without touching files?

Please let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

if this is something that you will do one time, I would suggest create a new table with the expected partitions and insert the table from the older table to the new one using dynamic partitioning. This will also avoid keep small files in your partitions. The other option is create a new table pointing to the old location with the expected partitions and use  the following properties

```
TBLPROPERTIES ("hive.input.dir.recursive" = "TRUE", 
"hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories" = "TRUE",
"hive.supports.subdirectories" = "TRUE", 
"mapred.input.dir.recursive" = "TRUE");
```

after that, you can run the msck repair table to recognize the partitions.